# Animations in SciLab

Tags: scilab

I want to plot the trajectory of a simple spring mass system using SciLab. I have successfully managed to plot a graph of x vs t. Now I want to make a gif of the trajectory of the body with respect to time (something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAl4XATyke4). How am I supposed to go about it? Attached is my progress till now.

```
//Input the spring constant k, mass m. and the initial values of x and x dot. The code will plot both x (in red) and x dot (in green)

function sol = spingmass(k,m,x_initial,xdot_initial,time)
osqr = k/m;

function dx = f(t,x)
    dx(1)=x(2);
    dx(2)=-1*osqr*x(1);
endfunction

t = 0:0.1:10;
sol = ode([x_initial;xdot_initial],time,t,f);
clf;
plot(t,sol(1,:),'r');
plot(t,sol(2,:),'g');
//disp(sol);

endfunction
```

Comment: And what is the issue with your progress?

Comment: There is no issue. I want to extend this. I want to show the animation the trajectory of the body (not the x vs t plot) Something like this

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAl4XATyke4

Comment: You should try to make it yourself. If you came up with an issue, please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ask it in Stackoverflow.

Comment: To help you can first draw the mass at its initial position and get the handle on the graphical entity associated with it (let it called h for example). Then integrate the differential equation as you have done, then for each sol(k,1) update the h.data field...

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to build an animated GIF with a series of Scilab snapshots of a graphical figure thanks to the animaGIF toolbox available @ https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/animaGIF

It is a standalone toolbox. No dependency like imageMagick or other GIMP is required.

The single animaGIF() function of the toolbox is extensively documented.
The documentation includes some animated GIF figures, moving in the Scilab help browser. Enjoy!